# sample size calculation of random coefficient negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, sample-size, negative-binomial-distribution

Please help me with calculating the minimum sample size of random coefficients for a negative binomial regression. I am wondering if a group receiving an intervention will have a significant difference or lessen the use of seclusion towards a patient in a mental health unit, compared to that of a group without the intervention. I am controlling for the site and the patient, to cancel out the effects of the site and avoid violation of non-independence of data, because there is a possibility that each patient may still be admitted the next day and be secluded. Also, there is no certainty as to how long the patient will be admitted. Below is my `lme4` model:

```
model1 <- glmer.nb(SEC ~ INT + (1|SIT/MRN), data=full_data)
```

where, SEC is the outcome variable, INT is the predictor, controlling for the MRN (i.e., person/patient) and the SIT (i.e., site) where the patient is.

Let me please know if the model is coded wrong in R, and how to compute for the sample size.

Comment: You are trying to find out how many sites/people you need to have a properly powered mixed model?